# Audio Recording Mac app with Visualizations unable to select input device with AudioKit

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession, audiokit, avcapturedevice

Hey I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am building a Mac Audio App that I need to perform the following actions

- Select audio input device
- Show a live audio graph of device input (think GarageBand/ Logic)
- capture the audio for replay
- Output the sound or make itself selectable as an input device for another app - Similar to how plugins work for GarageBand Logic etc

I have looked into using the following so far:

- AudioKit
- AVFoundation / AVCaptureDevice

`AudioKit`

This framework looks amazing and has sample apps for most of the things I want to do, however it seems that it will only accept the audio input that the Mac has selected in settings. This is a non starter for me as I want the user to be able to chose in App (like GarageBand does or Neural Dsp plugins)

Using `AudioEngine` I can get the available input devices, but everything I have found points to them not being changeable in App - here's code to display them

```
struct InputDevicePicker: View {
    @State var device: Device
    var engine: AudioEngine

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Input: \(device.deviceID)", selection: $device) {
            ForEach(getDevices(), id: \.self) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        .onChange(of: device, perform: setInputDevice)
    }

    func getDevices() -> [Device] {
        AudioEngine.inputDevices.compactMap { $0 }
    }

    func setInputDevice(to device: Device) {
      // set the input device on the AudioEngine
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively

`AVFoundation`

This has a nice API for listing devices and setting the input, but when it comes to working with the data the delegate provides, I don't have the first clue how I would handle this  in terms creating an audio graph and saving the data for replay. Here's the delegate method for reference

```
extension Recorder: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        print("Audio data recieved")
        // Needs to save audio here
        // Needs to play through speakers or other audio source
        // Need to show audio graph
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone with experience using these could advise if this is possible on either and where I can look for examples / guidance

Any help pointers, life savers would be appreciated

Thanks if you got this far !

Comment: After some quick research, the AVFoundation api seems good. To save the data, for example: let audioBufferList = AudioBufferList.fromCMSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer), then "let data = Data(bytes: audioBufferList.memory.mBuffers.mData!,
                count: Int(audioBufferList.memory.mBuffers.mDataByteSize))" to read it in. For the alternative, Core Audio APIs could be used to achieve this. A good starting point could be the AudioObjectGetPropertyData function, but seems low-level.